# Xamarin Android - problems creating bindings

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm creating bindings for eezee POS and eeZee PAY for xam. android and iOS.

Thankfully, most of the binding of eeZee POS/Pay is very straight forward. However, there are a couple of issues, I'm not sure on how to fix

First - I have a method that is the same as the class it is in. Is there a way to map the method or classname to something different? It looks like I should be able to map in the metadata.xml file.

Next is that I have a couple of methods that look like this

```
public static string Bold (params global:: string[] content)
```

this fails to build as there isn't a name after the `global::`. There isn't any form of mapping on this, so it there a way to remove the `global::` in one of the transform files?

Finally, If I manually fix 1 and 2 and build, I produce the dlls without a hitch. When I come to use the pos binding, I get `Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError (com.thepaymenthouse.ezpossdk,EZFactory$1)` thrown. From what I can see this means something hasn't bound correctly. Is there a way to trace this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read in depth how the documentation for iOS and Android library binding provided by Xamarin, here are the link.

iOS -> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/

Android -> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/

In particular regarding your first question I think you are talking about Xamarin Android binding, considering that you mentioned metadata.xml. To solve your problem you simply have to add a rule inside your metadata.xml as follow

NewName

details are at the following link

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/#Renaming_Members

Your second problem is a little misleading, could you explain it better? Where is that portion of code?

Regarding your last error Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError, I think that something went wrong during your binding. Considering that the error is related to Java binding you can check under the directory of your "binding project", in the folder obj/"debug or release"/generated which are the classes generated by your project and see if there is the one you are lookin for.